# Map markers in street view

Tags: google-maps

First of all, I'm not really sure if this question is really for Stack Overflow, please tell me where I should move it if it's necessary.

Is it possible to add custom pins (map markers) in Google Maps Street View? If the answer is "yes" please provide additional information about how it can be done (links to sources, tips, etc.). Tried searching on Google for "google maps street view markers" but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is possible

you can easy found sample like [this  on google dev](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays)

this is the js sample code by google development

```
var panorama;

function initMap() {
  var astorPlace = {lat: 40.729884, lng: -73.990988};

  // Set up the map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: astorPlace,
    zoom: 18,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  // Set up the markers on the map
  var cafeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.730031, lng: -73.991428},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
      title: 'Cafe'
  });

  var bankMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.729681, lng: -73.991138},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=dollar|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bank'
  });

  var busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 40.729559, lng: -73.990741},
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=bus|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bus Stop'
  });

  // We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
  // Note that we don't yet set it visible.
  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(astorPlace);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));
}

function toggleStreetView() {
  var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
  if (toggle == false) {
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    panorama.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```